# Travelling the world

Tags: riddle, rhyme, steganography

Yesterday, I received a text message from one of my best friends:

> This is great, Ryan. This trip is so wonderful, best day ever dude! Wow!

Well, I guess he's having fun right now while I'm sitting at my desk, working... I was curious to know more about his trip (offered by his parents, the dude's been gone for 3 months now), and of course what countries or cities he had visited. This was his answer:

> You may think that travelling is easy
>   But I had to make it through security
>   Not one nor two, but eighteen times!
>   I tell you, it's you who'll get the primes...
>   Forget it, most important thing is to get some sleep
>   Or else it would have felt like wasting my youth!
>   Don't focus on the rhymes, they're not so deep,
>   Concentrate on the list you'll find, here lies the truth.

Can you help me find out what these lines mean, and where my friend has been this whole time?

Hint:

> The steganography tag is for the first text message. The riddle is here to help you find out what the message hides.

Hint 2:

> Apparently, my friend hid the countries/cities he visited in the first text message only! How can it be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text message is very short and yet contains a steganographically hidden message, so presumably the solution involves manipulation of individual *letters* rather than words.

*But I had to make it through security*
*Not one nor two, but eighteen times!*

> The number of letters in the text message is exactly $3\times18$, so we can split it up into eighteen three-letter strings. Three-letter strings could be interpreted as airport codes - this would explain why your friend had to pass through security eighteen times, once for each of these airports.
>
>  THI
>  SIS
>  GRE
>  ATR
>  YAN
>  THI
>  STR
>  IPI
>  SSO
>  WON
>  DER
>  FUL
>  BES
>  TDA
>  YEV
>  ERD
>  UDE
>  WOW

*I tell you, it's you who'll get the primes...*

> Let's try choosing just the primes-numbered airports from the above list; perhaps this shorter list is of the places he's actually been.
>
>  The 2nd is SIS - Sishen, South Africa.
>  The 3rd is GRE - Greenville Municipal Airport, USA.
>  The 5th is YAN - Yangambi, DR Congo.
>  The 7th is STR - Stuttgart, Germany.
>  The 11th is DER - Derim, Papua New Guinea.
>  The 13th is BES - Brest, France.
>  The 17th is UDE - Uden, Netherlands.

---

**Previous answer**

*But I had to make it through security*
*Not one nor two, but eighteen times!*

> It's surely significant that the number of letters in the text message is exactly $3\times18$, or $4\times18$ if we count spaces and punctuation. The first thing that springs to mind is considering every 3rd letter (or every 4th character, counting spaces and punctuation), but these give respectively:
>
>  ISERNIRIONRLSAVDEW
>  S AR.IRIONF TYEU !
>
>  ... neither of which seems to make much sense.

*I tell you, it's you who'll get the primes...*

> This seems to suggest taking all the letters/characters in prime-numbered positions. But applying this to the original message, either ignoring or counting spaces and punctuation, gives:
>
>  HIIGTYHSPOOUSDVE
>  HI SETYNHI  DR, VREO
>
>  ... and applying it to the 18-length strings we already found gives respectively:
>
>  SENRRSE
>   A.RFT
>
>  None of these results really makes much sense as it stands, but maybe one of them is close to something that does?

Comment: 3x18 is a good start. But what can you do with this information? Look at the new hint :)

Comment: @IAmInPLS I have a new idea, but it might be a bit tenuous ... airport codes?

Comment: @IAmInPLS See edit :-)

Comment: Nice! This is it. Passing eighteen times through security was a hint for the numbers of letters *and* that the things you'll find would be airports.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Wait, Ulan-Ude is actually UUD ... I can't find an airport with code UDE :-/

Comment: Oops you made a mistake indeed! I'll edit that. The codes are the IATA ones.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Huh, that's odd. I searched online for UDE as an airport code and couldn't find anything. It takes actually searching for "Uden Netherlands airport" to find it. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me

> There is a word in each line of the riddle which is a synonym.

So

> 1. Travelling - Trip
> 2. Looking at second line
> 3. Times - Day
> 4. Primes - Best
> 5. Important - Great
> 6. Looking at sixth line
> 7. Looking at seventh line
> 8. Looking at eighth line

Comment: The riddle is related to travelling, but you are way off! I'll add a hint :)